# Xcode refactoring error - "The Selection Does Not Contain Identifiable Content"

Tags: cocoa, xcode, refactoring

1. Select a method

   [Selection http://synapticmishap.co.uk/aSO/SelectionGrab.jpg](http://synapticmishap.co.uk/aSO/SelectionGrab.jpg)
2. Edit > Refactor...
3. Select "Move Up"
4. I get the following error a lot.

[Refactoring Error http://synapticmishap.co.uk/aSO/RefactoringError.jpg](http://synapticmishap.co.uk/aSO/RefactoringError.jpg)

Any ideas on how I can get Xcode to, well, do its job?

**Solution Summary**

Option 2 that Peter suggests below did the trick. I can't believe that

a) I didn't try this *Smacks head*

and

b)

Xcode couldn't find a sane way of saying "Don't select the whole method!"

Comment: What, exactly, did you select?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said this. I selected the whole of a single method in the class implementation. The class had a valid superclass that I'd coded too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Maybe that blank line at the start is screwing it up? Try starting the selection at the -/+.
2. Try right-clicking the first segment of the selector and Refactoring that.

Comment: Option 2 did the trick. I can't believe I didn't try that. How embarrassing. I suppose it could be worse - imagine how shameful it would be if I developed software for a living. Oh. That's right, I do. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

I tried refactoring a class (implementation) after I renamed the containing file manually and got the same error.  Once I renamed the file back to its original name I was able to refactor.